# Google Play API XML

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-layout

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps into an android app I am developing(Eclispe SDK), but my app keeps failing and I get an "error in XML" sometimes, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 **Emulator:**
```

Nexus 7 (7.27",800 x 1280: tvdpi)
RAM:600
VM Heap:32
internal Storage: 200 MiB
SD Card: 300 MiB

**MainActiviy.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.test.me.googlemapstest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission:android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.test.me.googlemapstest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>code here
```

This is what I got from the API guide, and it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

YOur layout is Incorrectly defined You are Starting with Linear Layout and Ending with Relative layout 
either make it Linear or Go with Relative
Corrected below

```
      <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was simply a copying error; it's <LinearLayout><LinearLayout/>, but still failing on the emulator

Comment: then show your logcat
your emulator is not Supporting Google Librray have you made emulator with Google Library ?

Comment: to run maps in emulator you must have to make emulator with Google API